# R packages and VCE option

Tags: r, standard-error, robust

I am a graduate student using R and Stata.

When I was working with both of the programs, I thought that "why do not R packages provide the VCE option?"
What I mean is that although we very frequently want to use the robust standard error, a lot of R packages do not mention the robust se argument explicitly.
So, my question is that is there any good way to replace the VCE option in R?
If there is a good way, there is no reason why I have to use STATA.

Thank you for your time spending to read this question.

Comment: Well if the package maintainer did not implement a robust option your SOL. If it is implemented it is probably documented somewhere how to turn it on. Since in R every package maintainer is free to implement what she*he likes to implement, you won't find a global option. So just use the option were appropiate. For basic methods there are some robust statistic packages, see also: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Robust.html.

Comment: Good points by @Julian_Hn. Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117052/replicating-statas-robust-option-in-r about a discussion of this topic and potential solutions.

Comment: @user12728748 Ah ... Very nice post you dug up there. I remember seeing that one ages ago